# Angular 10: Dynamically add input element for nested FormArray inside FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Here's the link to my [StackBlitz Demo App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-dynamic-inputs?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.component.ts)

I am trying to dynamically add input fields using FormBuilder array() method.

To get a clear vision look at my `ngOnInit()` and dependent methods

```
stackForm: FormGroup;

get work(): FormArray {
  return this.stackForm.get('work') as FormArray;
}

get highlights(): FormArray {
  return this.stackForm.get('work.highlights') as FormArray;
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.stackForm = new FormGroup({
        'work': this.fb.array([this.buildWork()])
    })        
}      

buildWork(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        company: '',
        position: '',
        summary: '',
        highlights: this.fb.array([this.buildHighlights()])
    });
}

buildHighlights(): FormControl {
    return new FormControl()
}
```

HTML implementation is like this:

```
<div formArrayName="highlights">
    <div [formGroupName]="j"
          *ngFor="let hg of highlights.controls; let j=index">
     <!-- input element -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting this error message on console, and my input fields are not shown.

> ERROR Error: ctx_r0.highlights is null

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Lotte-Lemmens, helped me figure out the `null` issue.
However, I cannot see a textbox on load. Maybe because it was null, how may I pass an empty value from the component so that it loops for once and I can see the textbox as well.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Eldar, I am able to see the textbox now, and add more for new highlights. On the Updated StackBlitz, there's still problem updating value of `stackForm` when hightlight is added. When I click on new highlight and add new highlight, the value is not added inside the `highlights` array in `stackForm.value`, only the first value is added.

But if i edit the first highlight (to recreate this issue, add multiple highlights first), all others are added into array at once.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need a few things to fix :

1. Reaching the `FormArray`

```
 <div [formGroupName]="j" *ngFor="let hg of highlights(i); let j=index">
```

Since you are accessing a Form Array (work is a FormArray) you need to access the correct form array item. For this you need to use an index like above.

2. To achieve goal 1. you need to change your `highlights` property into a function that accepts an index :

```
highlights(i :number): Array<FormControl> {
    let c =((this.stackForm.get('work') as FormArray).controls[i].get('highlights') as FormArray).controls as Array<FormControl>;
    return c;
}
```

3. And finally you can directly bind `formControl` instead using `formControlName`

```
<input class="form-control"
                              id="{{'highlightsId' + j}}"
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Highlights"
                              [formControl]="hg">
```

**Edit:**
For adding new highlights you need to change your method like below :

```
 addHighlights(i = 0): void {
    this.highLightFormArray(i).push(this.buildHighlights());
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-dynamic-inputs-rbfvgq?file=src/app/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Eldar, if I change highlights property into function than I get an error which checking valid state of highlights. Please check updated codebase.

Comment: The one you forked, I forgot to add a add new highlight button.

Comment: With the new `highlights`-function the button should just need a click-handler like `(click)="highlights(i).push(buildHighlights())"`

Comment: I have implemented your solution on my Stackblitz, also i am looking as how `stackForm.value` is changing, when I click on new highlight and add new highlight, the value is not added up inside the array, only the first value is added. Please check once.

Comment: Weird issue is, when i add another highlight there value is not updated on the json, but if i edit the first one (to recreate, add multiple highlights first), all others are added.

Comment: @LuzanBaral updated the stackblitz and answer. It was my mistake to modify that `addHighlights` method wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Eldar, you have been a great help.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, still I wanted to ask one more question, for now there was only highlights for work, now if i need to add highlight for another array, say product, how can I reuse same methods, I see we have passed `i` index, is there anyway we can pass like highlights for work, and highlight for product, or highlight for services,

Comment: @LuzanBaral You can make those methods accept another parameter as FormGroup's name and instead of using `this.stackForm.get('work')` you can use `this.stackForm.get(groupName)`

Comment: It too much to ask, but if you have time, can you please change your stackblitz to pass formGroupName

Comment: @LuzanBaral added a product sample

Comment: @Eldar I realized it today, that if I add a new Work, and try to add new highlight on second Work block, highlight is added in first Work block, what might be the reason?

Comment: @LuzanBaral that was my mistake. While adding the product sample I mistakenly deleted the index argument passed to `addHighlight` method, updated stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

In the stackblitz you made, thanks for that, I can add a question mark toyour ngFor items. This solves the error on stackblitz

```
"let w of work?.controls; let i=index"
"let hg of highlights?.controls; let j=index"
```

This will first check if work/highlights exist, then loop over the controls.
I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I hope it is...

Comment: Yes, it solve the error of highlights being null, however i am not seeing one textbox for highlights, how can i make it show at least one textbox at load.